# prevent to have empty tag appear with no word

Tags: jquery

```
$('.btn-tag').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addTag();

});

$('#tags').bind({
    keyup: function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == 32) { //Enter keycode
            addTag();
        }
    },
    keypress: function(e) {
        if (e.which === 32)
            return false;
    },

});

$('#tags').bind('copy paste', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});


$('.tags-box').on('click', '.tag-delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    limitofTags();
    compileTags();
});

limitofTags();


function addTag() {
    var tag = $.trim($('#tags').val());
    if (tag !== '') {
        var $tagItem = $('<div class="tag"><a href="" class="tag-delete"><i class="icn-delete"></i></a>' + tag + '</div>');
        $tagItem.appendTo('.tags-box');
        $('#tags').val('');
        limitofTags();
        compileTags();
    }
}

function compileTags() {

    var tags = $('.tags-box').find('.tag').map(function() {
        var text = $.trim($(this).text());
        if (!text) {
            return text;
        }
    }).get().join(",");
    $('#tagsAdd').val(tags);
}

//Limiting number of Tags
function limitofTags() {
    var tags = $('.tags-box').find('.tag').map(function() {
        var text = $.trim($(this).text());
        if (!text) {
            return text;
        }
    }).get();

    $("#tags").prop('disabled', tags.length >= 12);
    var limit = 12;
    var $counter = $('.numoftags');
    var remains = parseInt(limit - tags.length);

    if (remains == 1) {
        $counter.text(remains + ' more tags');
    } else if (tags.length >= limit) {

        $counter.text('Cannot display anymore tags');
    } else {

        $counter.text('Add ' + remains + ' more tags');
    }
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="fieldcontain  ">
    <h3> Tags </h3>

    <input type="text" name="tags" id="tags">

    <input type="hidden" name="tagsAdd" value="" id="tagsAdd">

    <a href="" class="btn-tag">Add</a>
    <div class="tag-count">
      <small>
          <div class="numoftags">Add 12 more tags</div>
      </small>
    </div>
    <div class="tags-box">



    </div>
  </div>
```

Strange, return false doesn't stop the tags-box container to display blank tags which shouldn't be allowed. I wanted it to check if all tags in tags-box container has words before displaying tags. How to prevent tag with no words from appearing after I save draft or publish?

Help appreciated!

Comment: console.log the text what does it show when the tag is empty?

Comment: try adding `text != '' || text != null `

Comment: @PatsyIssa - i put console.log but it doesn't print anything but val(tags) does return blank when saving tag

Comment: @S.Varun - no it doesn't work. when i save the draft or publish, it will still appear with no word.

Comment: @kittymeows can you please add your full source for testing

Comment: @S.Varun ok wait i will post

Comment: @S.Varun - here is the full code

Comment: @kittymeows k i will check any you can try other answers too

Comment: @S.Varun yes I have tried other answers but nothing helps :(

Comment: @kittymeows Here it works correctly

Comment: @S.Varun it worked correctly except that its dynamic and also it would be create page then once save draft or publish, it will show tag with no text if i didnt put tag

Comment: @kittymeows can you create a JS Fiddle demo for your problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/). Add relevant jQuery library as well.

Comment: @kittymeows You use php ? to retrive the data ?

Comment: @S.Varun - grails controller to retrieve the data and display

Comment: @kittymeows try to check for incoming data.. just debug the tag data

Comment: @S.Varun will do. one more tag saved in IE doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this instead?

```
 function compileTags() {

    var tags = $('.tags-box').find('.tag').map(function() {
        var text = $.trim($(this).text());
        if (!text) {
            return text;
        }
    }).get().join(",");
    $('#tagsAdd').val(tags);
}
```